# Are R-colored diphthongs phonemes or not?

Tags: rhoticity, diphthongs, phonemes

There are some sounds called the "R-colored diphthong" in English, such as [or] sound in "court" or the [ir] sound in "clear".

My question is simple: are these R-colored diphthongs regarded as phonemes, respectively for native speakers?

Answer (score 2):

How can you tell?

I think the right thing to do is ask a bunch of Americans who haven't thought much about phonetics whether the vowel in *beard* is the same as the vowel in *bead* or as the vowel in *bid*. If they instantly answer *bead* (or *bid*), then you know that for them /ir/ is an allophone of /i/ (or /ɪ/). If they hesitate and can't decide instantly, you can conclude that *beard* has its own phoneme.

Has anybody actually tried this experiment? Not as far as I know. What answer would you get if you did? My guess is that some Americans think of the vowel in /ir/ as an allophone of /i/, some as an allophone of /ɪ/, and some think of /ir/ as its own phoneme.

For me, as far as I can tell, the vowel of /ir/ is an allophone of /ɪ/, but /ɔr/ is definitely its own phoneme.  I pronounce it /or/ and don't perceive it as either /ɔ/ or /oʊ/.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, rhotic vowels generally aren't regarded as separate vowel phonemes. But I am not a linguist so you shouldn't take my word for it. Hopefully someone else will post a better answer soon.

As a native speaker of a rhotic variety of English, I do think a somewhat convincing argument can be made that rhotic vowels are phonemes. For example, I have the *[cot-caught](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#Cot.E2.80.93caught_merger)* merger, so for me the phoneme /ɔ/ doesn't occur anywhere except before /r/. That's a pretty odd distribution. Now, I also have the *horse-hoarse* merger, so we could just analyze my [ɔr] as consisting phonemically of tautosyllabic /oʊr/ (assuming we're going with something like John Wells's theory of English syllabification where a word like "glory" gets divided as "glor.y," the stress drawing the intervocalic consonant into the coda of the preceding syllable). But I think it's reasonable enough to analyze it as a diphthong instead. It behaves fairly similarly in some ways to /ɔɪ/ (it also has [ɔ] as the first element, and it can result in some cases from historical sequences of /ɔ/ + a consonant (for example, "drawer" /drɔ˞/ and "lawyer" /lɔɪɚ/).

Comment: I don't have the *cot-caught* merger, and I have quite different vowels in *court* and *caught*, and in *gourd* and *good*, and slightly different ones in *cart* and *cot*. I think for many Americans, the /r/-influenced vowels have come unmoored from the other vowels, so the vowel sound in *beard* isn't the same as either *bid* or *bead*.